# Algorithms: Remember the last n unique numbers, in order

Tags: algorithm

I want to remember the last n unique numbers, in order.

Here is what I mean: Let's say n = 4.

My current list is `5 3 4 2` If I add 6, it turns into `3 4 2 6`. If I add 3 instead, the list turns into `5 4 2 3`, where 3 moves to the front.

I would do it like this: Store the numbers in a queue. When adding a new number, search through the queue for the number. If the number is not found, pop the number at the end, and push the new number in the front. If the number is found, remove the number at that position, then push the new number in front.

Now obviously, removing a number from an arbitrary position in a queue, optimized for queue operations (like `std::deque` in C++) will be quite slow. Using a linked list, though will be slower to search through the list. Is there a better combination of algorithm + data structure to accomplish this sort of task?

If it makes any difference, I don't necessarily care about "remembering the last n unique numbers, in order." I specifically need to know, what element has been removed from the list upon an addition (if any).

Comment: I don't know if vector/queue/list would be best, did you try profiling?  Also, is `n` always going to be less than ~30?  Also, is the order important?

Comment: why search through the list is slower?

Comment: @JustinDanielson, it is not homework

Comment: @xvatar because a data structure optimized for queue operations will probably have better memory locality

Comment: @newprogrammer in case of search, i doubt how big the difference would be. you can run some simple tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a doubly linked list. You can add your n numbers to be remembered in a hash table where the key is the number itself and the value a pointer that points to the node of the linked list that contains that number.

Then in the step you describe  **search through the queue for the number** you change it for **look if the number is in the hash table** which will be constant time instead of liner time using the queue.

The pop and push operations you describe can be performed in constant time if you store a pointer p that points to the first element of the doubly linked list and a pointer q that points to the last element of your list.

Your step **If the number is found, remove the number at that position** can be performed in constant time since you already have the position of the number to be removed.(by position I mean the pointer you get from the hash table).

UPDATE:

Be careful that you must update your hash table to remove and add new numbers accordingly.